# Tensorflow doesn't start training at fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I've followed the evalutating [MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) and wanted to adapt it to use my own dataset. Using the inception model I've converted my images to tensors using build_image_data.py and loaded them. Then I tried using them as input for the model, but execution stops right up until the model.fit() function. No CPU usage an no output whatsoever after that.

Here is the relevant code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.contrib import learn
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import model_fn as model_fn_lib

import image_processing
import dataset

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

height = 200
width = 200

def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, width, height, 1])

    con
    v1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer, filters=32, kernel_size=[5, 5], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1, filters=64, kernel_size=[5, 5], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, (width/4) * (width/4) * 64])
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=2)

    loss = None
    train_op = None

    if mode != learn.ModeKeys.INFER:
        onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=2)
        loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)

    if mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(loss=loss, global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(), learning_rate=0.001, optimizer="SGD")

    predictions = {
            "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
            "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
    }

    return model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps(mode=mode, predictions=predictions, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

def main(unused_argv):
    training_data = dataset.Dataset("train-00000-of-00001", "train")
    validation_data = dataset.Dataset("validation-00000-of-00001", "validation")
    images, labels = image_processing.inputs(training_data)
    vimages, vlabels = image_processing.inputs(validation_data)

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    feature_classifier = learn.SKCompat(learn.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/feature_model"))
    tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
    logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=10)
    feature_classifier.fit(x=images.eval(), y=labels.eval(), batch_size=100, steps=200000, monitors=[logging_hook])
    metrics = {
            "accuracy":
                    learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn=tf.metrics.accuracy, prediction_key="classes"),
    }
    # Evaluate the model and print results
    eval_results = feature_classifier.evaluate(x=vimages.eval(), y=vlabels.eval(), metrics=metrics)
    print(eval_results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

The only output it gives at the very start is:

> INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_tf_config': gpu_options {
>     per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 1
>   }
>   , '_tf_random_seed': None, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_task_id': 0, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_task_type': None, '_num_worker_replicas': 0, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_evaluation_master': '', '_cluster_spec': , '_environment': 'local', '_model_dir': None}

My dataset is about 31 MB + 6 MB for the input and validation set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the queue runners. The following code changes should work:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
coordinator = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess,coord=coordinator)

feature_classifier = learn.SKCompat(learn.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/feature_model"))
 ...

print(eval_results)
coordinator.request_stop()
coordinator.join(threads)
```

Another recommended way is to use the updated Estimator 'input_fn' method by making the following changes:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

feature_classifier = learn.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/feature_model")
tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=10)
feature_classifier.fit( input_fn=lambda:image_processing.inputs(training_data), train=True), steps=200000, monitors=[logging_hook])
metrics = {
        "accuracy":
                learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn=tf.metrics.accuracy, prediction_key="classes"),
}
```

Comment: Hi, after removing ", train=True)" the model starts learning on my cpu. Now I just have to fix it running out of memory on my gpu. Thank you.

Comment: To fix your GPU memory problem, make the image_processing module to run on CPU. Check the best practices performance guide from tensoflow : https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide

Comment: I use this from the inception model: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/image_processing.py which seems to do exactly that. But if I reduce the numbers of neurons from 1024 to 512 it trains on my 2GB gpu.